# What does conservation of strangeness imply for the nature of interaction?

Tags: particle-physics, conservation-laws

If the conservation of strangeness holds for a decay, then the possible interactions are *Strong*, *Electromagnetic* and *Weak*.

But how does one determine which one is it, out of the three?

Comment: Well first there isnt a conservation law for strangeness for decays, a strange particle may decay to normal non-strange particles

Comment: What if the strangeness number before and after a decay are the same, what can I conclude thus about the interaction force?

Comment: Nothing actually, the violation of this is a result of the weak force, the electromagnetic and strong forces do not violate any conservation laws. His is what makes weak interaction physics so interesting

Comment: Either that or if it is vonserved in the reaction then the reaction doesnt proceed via the weak force but the strong or electromagnetoc instead, this might be the result youre looking for

Comment: So if strangeness on both sides are equal to each other, the only conclusion I can make is that the interaction is either electromagnetic or Strong force. 
If the strangeness number is not equal on both sides, then the interaction proceeds via the weak force?
It is extremely important that I understand this before I proceed further into quarks.

Comment: Yeah that is likely a good guess as the strong and EM interactions preserve such quantities, its due to the fact that the weak force mixes lepton generations where as the EM and strong do not

Comment: If the strangeness is equal on both sides, is it possible then to tell if the interaction is via strong or electromagnetic?

Comment: Well it does get a little more complicated than that, this is why strangeness isn't a good number to use all the time, there are in fact some weak reactions that do conserve strangeness. You may also ahve to look at the time scale of the interaction (compute the lifetime of a given particle decay mode), te strong interaction has very quick processes. I shouldnt have said that it isnt possible for it to be weak, just less likely